# Конвертирование HttpPostedFile в FileStream

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода, asp.net-web-api

Есть метод в сервесном слое вот с такой сигнатурой:

```
public class FileService : IFileService
{               
    public int AddToRepository(string userName, FileStream fileStream)
    {
        //..

        var fileName = fileStream.Name;

        //..
    }
}
```

и есть API-контроллер с экшеном для добавления файла в репозиторий:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/files")]
[Authorize]
public HttpResponseMessage AddFileToRepository()
{
    var userName = User.Identity.Name;
    var httpFileCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    if (httpFileCollection.Count == 0)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Body has not file");

    HttpPostedFile postedFile = httpFileCollection.Get(0);
    int idAddedFile;

    //..
    // Код для добавления файла, используя сервис IFileService 
    //..

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, idAddedFile);
}
```

---

Чтобы воспользоваться методом `FileService.AddToRepository()` с текущей сигнатурой мне необходимо каким-то образом конвертировать `HttpPostedFile` в `FileStream`. Все мои попытке на этот счет были счетны т.к. `FileStream` предполагает наличие реально существующего файла *(если я все правильно понял)*.

Было пару решений и остановился я на втором

**1)** Делать отдельный метод с сигнатурой

`int AddToRepository(HttpPostedFile, string userName)` не хочется, т.к. приходится тащить зависимость `System.Web` в сервис, который в свою очередь планируется использовать как в десктопных, так и в мобильный приложениях. Но тем не менее я такой метод тоже делал, но так и не смог замокать объект `HttpPostedFile` в юнит-тестах.

**2)** И теперь я перегрузил метод

```
public int AddToRepository(string userName, Stream stream, string fileName)
{
    //..

    var fileStream = stream;

    //..
}
```

и планирую пользоваться им так

```
public HttpResponseMessage AddFileToRepository()
{
    var userName = User.Identity.Name;
    var httpFileCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    if (httpFileCollection.Count == 0)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Body has not file");

    HttpPostedFile postedFile = httpFileCollection.Get(0);
    int idAddedFile = fileService.AddToRepository(userName, postedFile.InputStream, postedFile.FileName);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, idAddedFile);
}
```

---

### Вопрос

Можно ли было как-то конвертировать `HttpPostedFile` в `FileStream` и не делать тем самым дополнительный метод. Спрашивая по другому: что говорит практика хорошего дизайна в таких ситуациях?